# Page does not get render on refresh in react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have Routes declared in `App.tsx` file like this:

```js
<Router>
  {!auth.loading && (
    <Switch>
      {!auth.user && <Redirect exact from="/" to="/auth" />}
      {auth.user && <Redirect exact from="/auth" to="/home" />}
      {!auth.user && <Redirect exact from="/home" to="/auth" />}
      {!auth.user && <Redirect exact from="/profile" to="/auth" />}

      <Route path="/auth">
        <AuthPage />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/project/:projectId">
        <ProjectPage />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/profile/:userId">
        <ProfilePage />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/profile">
        <ProfilePage />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/home">
        <HomePage />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  )}
</Router>
```

The refresh problem occurs in parameterized routes `/profile/:userId` and `/project/:projectId`.
What happens is that the page loads on the first time, and when I try to refresh it, nothing gets rendered.

Comment: try to put `exact` on `<Route exact path="/profile" component={ProfilePage}  />`. Will that do the trick for you?

Comment: Are you rendering two `Router` components in your app by any chance?

Comment: @DrewReese no i am not

Comment: @lala tried but the problem persists

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you clarify what you mean by "nothing gets render"? Upon refresh/reload is the page blank, or are you saying it isn't rerendered with new content? Think you could create a reproducible example in a *running* codesandbox?

Comment: @DrewReese yeah, the page gets blank on refresh

Comment: If you comment out all but one parameterized route and have it render something simple like `<div>TEST</div>`, does it work? If you add back in just the component? Could you try some logging in the component when it mounts and/or rerenders? Just try reducing down to a simple code that works and add bits back in until it breaks and then you know where you should dig into.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224961/discussion-between-jastor-007-and-drew-reese).